Properly allocating a memory region and accessing the underlying hardware addresses
I am trying to interact with an IP hardware design, that is flashed on an FPGA matrix, from a Linux program. The communication takes place over the AXI bus. Character devices receive commands from user space in the form of 4-byte words that are forwarded to the IP.
This IP communicates with storage devices, and transfers the contents of a memory region (whose address is specified through the commands sent over AXI) to the device.
However, attempting to transfer a file means mapping that file in memory, then getting the hardware address to transfer it to the FPGA (since it is not aware of the virtual memory layout).
I am looking for a solution that would ideally allow me to call mmap(2) from a user space program to map the file, even if an underlying driver is required.
I tried simply using mmap(2) and converting the address using virt_to_phys(), but it obviously failed, as the latter requires kernel logical addresses.
I am aware there may be a solution using the DMA API, but I am unfamiliar with it and as such am unsure how to proceed.

Contiguous virtual pages may not be physically contiguous. Does your hardware support scatter-gather?

Unfortunately, it is one of those pieces of hardware that does not have scatter-gather enabled, at least not on the interface that I have to use. Hence my problem, really, it would be much easier without the contiguous layout constraint !
